# Makefile pattern matching

Tags: makefile

There are two pattern rules in my Makefile. target1 actually matches both these two rules. When I run the makefile, it always try to run the recipes of pattern rule1 instead of pattern rule2 I desire. For a specific target(target1 for example), is it possible to have makefile process skip matching rule1 and go ahead to find the second match(rule2)???

```
  ## pattern rule 1
    %.xml: $^
       recipes ....

  ## pattern rule 2
    /opt/test1/xml/default%.xml: $^
       recipes ....

  ## target1
    /opt/test1/xml/default1.xml: prereq
```

Comment: Something's not right here. The automatic variable `$^` has no value in the prerequisite list. Are you sure these rules do what you think they do?

Comment: Also, which version of Make are you using?